# I'm trying to run dynamic form controls validation inside ngfor, but I don't know how to access or call the control

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formbuilder, formgroups

Below is the code of what i have. Everything works fine except for the error message. I keep getting

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasError')

```
<div    *ngFor='let x of objectKeys(tempValidation_fields) ; let i = index '>
                 
    <label  class="form-control-label px-3">{{x}}
        <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="tempValidation_fields[x].IsRequired === true "> *</span>
    </label>
                  
    <input *ngIf="  type="text" class="form-control" id=x name=x placeholder="Enter {{x}}"
                  formControlName={{x}}  >

    <div class="text-danger mt-2" *ngIf="myForm.controls[x].hasError('pattern')">
        <p>Invalid Format</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you please share the `objectKeys` method and `tempValidation_fields`? How do they look alike?

Comment: Also, are all these form fields part of `myForm`, added these dynamic fields from component? please show code

Comment: `<input *ngIf=" ` could be a typo. check this once.

Comment: I imagine should be `*ngIf="x.IsRequired"` and `[formControlName]="x"` and `myForm.get(x).hasError('pattern')"` or `myForm.hasError('pattern',x)"`